# disable auto adjust uitableView inset

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

### UIViewController

### ContainerView   -> UITableViewController
UIView
ContainerView   -> UIViewController

When the keyboard is shown, the UITableViewController in UIViewController automatically adjusts the contentInset.

So, I add this code in UITableViewController

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
} else {
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}
```

But it does not work. How can I disable auto inset?

Comment: have you check your device or simulator iOS version.?

Comment: @MRizwan33 yes, both iOS 10.3 and iOS 11 have same problem

Comment: try to write your code in viewcontroller which has container view.

Comment: @MRizwan33 but UIViewController does not have tableView, so I can not use contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior. and "self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false" in UIViewController also no effect.

Comment: try to do this via storyboard. ViewController which has container view. uncheck the layout : Adjust Scroll View Insects.

Comment: @MRizwan33 I already set that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the perfect solution!

```
UITableView.appearance().contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

just add this code in UITableViewController. and strange adjust inset all gone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply to the ViewController which contains the ContainerView (with the UITableView inside of it). It does not work when applied to the UITableView itself.

Or via code in viewDidLoad(): self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Comment: did you checked adjust scroll from uitableview?

Comment: can you provide image descriptions?

Comment: I found the solution. "UITableView.appearance().contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never" is working perfectly in this case!